# Python Quicksort function goes to infinite loop

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, infinite-loop, quicksort

i have a list of dictionaries contacts.

```
contacts = [{'first':'asasdasd', 'last':'sddafs','email':'asdsadas'},
{'first':'asasdasd', 'last':'sddafs','email':'asdsadas'}]
```

I would like to sort dictionaries in the list by key 'last', using quicksort algorithm.

```
less = []
greater = []

def qsort_last(listD):
    if len(listD) < 2:
        return listD
    else:
        pivot = contacts[0]['last']
        for i in range(len(listD)):
            if listD[i]['last'] <= pivot:
                less.append(listD[i])
            else:
                greater.append(listD[i])
        return qsort_last(less) + [contacts[0]] + qsort_last(greater)

print(qsort_last(contacts))
```

Now function goes to infinite loop. Please advise.

Comment: what is `listD`? You haven't shown us your function call with `listD` as an argument

Comment: Agree, it seems like you are mixing up contacts and listD or something.

Comment: excuse me, already updated

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is you keep adding elements to your `less` and `greater` lists, so they will keep growing without bound.

Also, you are duplicating the pivot element because of `<=` in your if clause.

Try this:

```
def qsort_last(listD):
    less = []
    greater = []

    if len(listD) < 2:
        return listD
    else:
        pivot = listD[0]['last']
        for i in range(len(listD)):
            if listD[i]['last'] < pivot:
                less.append(listD[i])
            elif listD[i]['last'] > pivot:
                greater.append(listD[i])
        return qsort_last(less) + [contacts[0]] + qsort_last(greater)
```

Comment: for i in range(len(listD)):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: with 2 dictionaries in the list it works, but if there are 9 dictionaries : maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: Because there's another bug, you're always using contacts[0] as the pivot, instead of listD[0]. Fixed that, should work now.

Answer (score 0):

updated. Now it works .Thank you everybody for help.

```
def qsort_last(listD):
    less = []
    greater = []
    middle=[]
    if len(listD) < 2:
        return listD
    else:
        pivot = listD[0]['last']
        for i in range(len(listD)):
            if listD[i]['last'] < pivot:
                less.append(listD[i])
            elif listD[i]['last'] > pivot:
                greater.append(listD[i])
            elif listD[i]['last'] == pivot:
                middle.append(listD[i])

        return qsort_last(less) + middle + qsort_last(greater)
```